# Recursive :include in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, include, polymorphism

I have a polymorphic model that can relate to itself:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end
```

These relationships work perfectly, except when I'm trying to call the full tree of child/parent comments through an `include` statement:

```
Post.find(1).include(:comments)
```

This only includes the comments directly tied to the post. I could perhaps retrieve a second level with:

```
Post.find(1).include(comments: :comments)
```

But what if I wanted to get all comments descending from the post, no matter how deeply nested? Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you want to retrieve an adjacency list. Rails has no immediate support for it, but if you are using postgresql, you can use the "WITH RECURSIVE" operator.

That plugin takes care of it : https://github.com/chrisroberts/acts_as_sane_tree

Otherwise, you can pretty easily create your own postgresql function (declare it in a migration), and then use it in your queries. Have a look at : http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Getting_list_of_all_children_from_adjacency_tree

WITH RECURSIVE is not currently implemented in mysql or sqlite3.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. Unfortunately, we're using mysql, but it's good to at least know what are options are limited to.